# IE11 not recognizing .loadXML()

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html, xml-parsing

Working on some xml data and my function works in all browsers except for IE10 and up.

Is there something else I can use instead of .loadXML(data)

Here is part of the transform function. it breaks at x.loadXML(data)

```
$.transform = function(o) {
        var createXmlObj = function(data) {
            if($.browser.msie) {
                var x = $("<xml>")[0];
                x.loadXML(data);
                return x;
            } else {
                var parser = new DOMParser();
                return parser.parseFromString(data,"text/xml");
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

add your page to Internet Explorer's Compatibility View Settings. You won't believe the types of issues that this fixes.